# How to write integration test in .net using test containers for Google spanner

Tags: testing, containers, integration, google-cloud-spanner

Trying to identify a way to spun test container using Google spanner for writing integration tests. All I'm able to find is how to spun test containers using postgres flavor.

Is there any utility available for this?

Comment: Would you mind adding a little bit more context to your question? Cloud Spanner is a cloud database that you cannot install locally, meaning that 'spinning up a test container with Cloud Spanner' also does not make any sense. Or are you trying to run the Cloud Spanner emulator (https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/emulator) in a container?

Comment: We working on integration tests using test containers for Google cloud spanner. For parallel execution of the test, we have to make sure we are able to generate or spin up test container for cloud spanner emulator for each test.w3 have readily available test container support for postgresql but not able to find support for cloud spanner emulator

Answer (score 0):

The Cloud Spanner emulator is available as a [pre-built Docker image](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/emulator#install-docker) that can be used in your test setup. You don't write what kind of CI environment that you are using that you are using, but the following shows an example of how you could set up a workflow that includes a Cloud Spanner emulator instance when using Github Actions:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - main
  pull_request:
name: integration-tests-against-emulator
jobs:
  units:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      emulator:
        image: gcr.io/cloud-spanner-emulator/emulator:latest
        ports:
          - 9010:9010
          - 9020:9020
```

The example is taken from the Cloud Spanner Java client library that uses this setup for integration tests. The full workflow definition can be found here: https://github.com/googleapis/java-spanner/blob/main/.github/workflows/integration-tests-against-emulator.yaml

You can use a single emulator instance for parallel integration tests by creating a separate database for each for each test that you have. You don't need a separate emulator Docker container for each test.

EDIT: I just noticed your reference to .NET in the title. A specific example for running integration tests on the Cloud Spanner emulator using .NET can be found here: https://github.com/googleapis/dotnet-spanner-entity-framework/blob/main/.github/workflows/integration-tests-on-emulator.yml